# browse button on server

Tags: asp-classic

When we put a browse button on an html form, it gives us the option to browse the file on our system only. If I run it on a server, will I be able to browse it on server paths? Basically I want to access the files available on the server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files shown are essentially "your files" - so if you are running the site on a server and browsing it from a different machine, you won't be able to see the files on the server.

If you run it on a server and browse the page from that server, you would be able to see the files.

Equally, if you are on the network and map a share on the server on your machine, you should also be able to browse that (using "Map Network Drive", which assigns the share on the server to a drive-letter on your machine).

Comment: well u just said what i require. what i want is to access files shared on the lan. how do i do it?

Comment: You can either... 1) browse to the file using "my network places" from within the upload dialog, or 2) map the network drive to a drive letter on your machine and browse via that.

Comment: This answers his question but the answer below gives options for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser control, so will only allow you to display files that are local to the browser.

If you want to show files on the server, you will need to use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28VS.85%29.aspx) and output lists to the browser.

Some examples you can look at are:

- http://www.micronetsoft.com/ws_webx.asp
- http://www.scriptdungeon.com/freeaspscript/freescripts8
- http://www.gleamtech.com/products/webexplorer/asp-file-manager

or just search "web file manager"

Comment: hey i am new to programming and just learnt fso. can u tell me a little precisely how do i do it. if possible may b some sample code.